# Issue with starting a new Task through Task.Run in OnResume (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have a "command queue" running that pumps messages out to a TCP server in my app. When the app goes to sleep, I stop the queue. When it resumes, I restart the queue. The Start and StopQueue functions are below.

```
    public void StartQueue()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    break;
                }
                await Task.Delay(Hz10);
                await UpdateAsync();
            }
        }, _cancellationToken);
    }

    public void StopQueue()
    {
        if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) return;
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
```

I can verify through the debugger that the queue is stopped successfully when the app goes to sleep (for example, pressing Home on an iPhone twice). I can also verify through the debugger that StartQueue is called when the app resumes (regains focus). However, none of my breakpoints in the Task.Run are hit after that. This leads me to believe the thread is not actually being recreated, as no breakpoints are hit in UpdateAsync or the task itself after resume.

Comment: Are you recreating the cancellation token before calling StartQueue ?

Comment: @wishmaster Bingo, thanks! Please add it as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: glad I helped, answer is posted. thanks @bodangly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure to initialize a new instance of _cancellationToken prior to calling StartQueue otherwise the Task will never run because the token is already in cancelled state.